# Multiple choice where questions are replaced with one answer in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Edit: For an updated version of the code discussed here, see this [codepen](http://codepen.io/bawpie/pen/AwmBJ).

I have a code [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HJixD) on codepen which I adapted from another code [here](http://codepen.io/JoshBlackwood/pen/yoLBJ).

Basically when you click one of the 3 options, the list of questions disappears and is replaced with the answer.

Here is the javascript:

```
  $('.inlinechoice').on('click','.link', function(e) {
  var $this = $(this),
  $id = $this.prop('id'),
  $class = '.' + $('.about-' + $id).prop('class').replace('hide', '');

  $('.default-text').addClass('hide');
  $('.about-' + $id).removeClass('hide');
  $('div[class*=about]').not($class).addClass('hide');
  });
```

Here is the html:

```
    <body>

    <div class="default-text">
    <div class="inlinechoice">
    <a href="#" class="link" id="1">Choice 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="link" id="2">Choice 2</a> 
    <a href="#" class="link" id="3">Choice 3</a>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="about-1 hide">
    <p>You picked 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="about-2 hide">
    <p>You picked 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="about-3 hide">
    <p>You picked 3</p>
    </div>
```

Here is the css:

```
 * { margin:0;padding:0; }
 body { background:#E9EEF5; }

 .default-text {
 font:20pt 'Georgia';
 height:50px;
 width:674px;
 margin:20px auto 0;
 text-align:center;
  }

 div {
 margin:20px auto 0;
 text-align:center;
 width: 674px;
  }

 .hide {
 display: none;
  }
```

Currently the JS uses css to hide and unhide the relevant information, but I'm wondering if it's possible to have this all done via javascript and html, without requiring the css part and if so, where would be the best place to start?

The reason I'm interested is I'm looking to create a custom macro (which allows use of javascript and jquery) for the Twine interactive fiction system which would allow people to include choices which don't progress to additional nodes (not dissimilar to the [*fake_choice command](http://choicescriptdev.wikia.com/wiki/Fake_choice) in Choicescript).   Obviously my javascript knowledge isn't up to much, so whilst I've managed to get up to this point (admittedly more through a combination of Google/Stackoverflow and Codepen than actually knowing anything about javascript), some additional thoughts or advice would be much appreciated!

Edit: Following the answer from @RyanS, I've made the changes to my code and it's doing what I want it to, thanks for the help!

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HkCgG

Comment: To be honest, I wasn't sure that it was a bad approach but I think it would mean making it into a macro for Twine easier (though I could be wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the jQuery show/hide:

```
$('.inlinechoice').on('click','.link', function(e) {
  var $this = $(this),
      $id = $this.prop('id'),
      $class = '.' + $('.about-' + $id).prop('class').replace('hide', '');

  $('.default-text').hide();
  $('.about-' + $id).show();
  $('div[class*=about]').not($class).hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks...though if I remove the css completely, and amend the div class names to remove the 'hide' part, they show initially.  The answers shouldn't appear until the option has been picked - is it possible to do this without requiring the css?  Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HkCgG

Comment: You could add some inline style, or execute some JS onload to hide them right away

Comment: Cool, that seems to work, I had no idea you could even do that.

Comment: @bawpie Awesome, glad to help. Check out the jQuery/jQuery UI api's, theres lots off cool stuff you can do http://api.jquery.com/