# Multiple choice where questions are replaced with answer with the ability to nest in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Edit:  I've made further improvements to the code posted here, which allows you to append data once all the questions have been answered in a particular branch.  See this [codepen](http://codepen.io/bawpie/pen/AwmBJ) for an example.

Okay, so I created a question here a few days ago which is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21562593/multiple-choice-where-questions-are-replaced-with-one-answer-in-javascript-or-jq), which I got some great help with and was able to tweak the javascript code I'd already amended to this:

```
    $('.inlinechoice').on('click','.question', function(e) {
      var $this = $(this),
          $id = $this.prop('id')

      $('.inlinechoice').hide();
      $('.answer-' + $id).show();
    });
```

Basically, it starts with a number of questions/options which are replaced with an appropriate answer when one of the questions is clicked.  Works great, does what I need it to do...except, I realised later that I wouldn't be able to nest more questions within the html because the javascript hides the choiceblock-text when a choice/question/option is clicked.

So, for instance if I wanted to do this:

```
    <div class="inlinechoice">
      <a class="question" id="1">Choice 1</a>
      <a class="question" id="2">Choice 2</a> 
      <a class="question" id="3">Choice 3</a>
    </div>

    <div style ="display:none" class="answer-1">
    You picked 1

    <div class="inlinechoice">
      <a class="question" id="4">Choice 4</a>
      <a class="question" id="5">Choice 5</a> 
    </div>

    </div>
    <div style="display:none"class="answer-2">
     You picked 2
    </div>
    <div style="display:none" class="answer-3">
     You picked 3
    </div>

    <div style="display:none"class="answer-4">
     You picked 4
    </div>
    <div style="display:none" class="answer-5">
     You picked 5
    </div>
```

It wouldn't work.  And I would like to do that if possible.

I think I need to add another variable which picks up the id of the choiceblock(similar to the answer id) so that it can show and hide the appropriate choiceblock but admittedly I'm struggling to get me head round to do it at the moment.  Also, I guess it's more complicated simply because when you click 'Question 1' with ID '1', it reveals answer '1' so I can see how the code does that.

However, when you click on something contained in choiceblock-1, I'd need to tell it to hide choiceblock-1 and possibly (but not always) unhide choiceblock-2, if the correct question had been clicked, which I guess could get very complicated depending on how many questions I'd want to nest (I'm thinking up to a maximum of 3, but possibly more?)?

Anyway, this is clearly something I need to think on and experiment with, but in the mean time if anyone has any advice or suggestions they would be most welcome!

Edit: Cleaned up original code as there were some parts in there that didn't need to be there I think.

Edit: I think I need 2 functions, one to set the .inlinechoice ID and one to set the .question id.

Codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HkCgG).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I managed to get something working I think.  As per my earlier edits to the original post, I realised that I needed to have 2 functions, one to show the answer and one to hide the inlinechoice depending on the id.  Now, I'm pretty sure that the way I've done this is not the best (or even recommended way) and there's probably a way to streamline and tidy the code, so I am really hoping someone can give me some tips regarding this.  For instance, the two functions are being called from clicking the inlinechoice, so I'm not sure I need to write this out twice, but one picks up the .question class id, and the other picks up the inlinechoice id.

```
        $('div[class*=inlinechoice').on('click','.question', function(e) {
          var $this = $(this),
              $id = $this.prop('id');

            $("#dialogue_container").append($('.answer-' + $id).contents());

        });

            $('div[class*=inlinechoice').on('click', function(a) {
              var $this = $(this),
              $cid = $this.prop('id');

              $('.inlinechoice-' + $cid).hide();


            });
```

If you look at the new codepen (linked below), and click through option 1, you'll see that the nesting works pretty well.

Anyways, I'll leave this here as an answer, but if anyone can improve or offer a better solution then I'd happily look at that.

Codepen: [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JwHuK)